# Simple, but I'm stuck ....Updating a DataSet using code

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataset

I have a simple Windows form in VB: textbox bound thru an adapter and a bindingsource to my dataset.

I have a button that on Click I want it to update the database.  The form loads and the first data row shows in the textbox, I change the text then click my button but no update happens.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or how I should do this??

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.AToolsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Qedsandb_TroyDataSet.aTools)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        AToolsTableAdapter.Update(Qedsandb_TroyDataSet.aTools)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does the click event run? Place a `MessageBox` as its first statement.

Comment: Check this .. http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets12p9.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the click event runs(?), TableAdapters based on a query (a join) do not, by default, have the ability to update the database. The name of your binding source suggests that you are using a query.

[MSDN: TableAdapter Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The update functionality of a TableAdapter is dependent on how much
>   information is available based on the main query provided in the
>   TableAdapter Wizard. For example, TableAdapters that are configured to
>   fetch values from multiple tables (JOINs), scalar values, views, or
>   the results of aggregate functions are not initially created with the
>   ability to send updates back to the underlying database. However, you
>   can configure the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands manually in the
>   Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be moving the data back from the form to the dataset. Try calling EndEdit on your bindingsource.